# What part of speech is "involving" in the sentence below, a gerund or a participle?

Tags: gerunds, participles

> Courts have had particular problems with situations involving the
>   purchase of software.

What part of speech is "**involving**" a gerund or a participle?

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's a participle as part of the larger adjectival phrase "involving the purchase of software", which modifies "situations".  A gerund is usually only a verbal noun, like "I like eating cake".

Answer (score 0):

It is the **present participle** in a **reduced defining relative clause** that is reduced to a [**present participle**](https://www.thoughtco.com/g00/reduced-relative-clauses-1211107?i10c.referrer=):

The complete sentence is:

- Courts have had particular problems with situations *that/which* involve the purchase of software.

To reduce a relative clause to a present participle:

1. Remove the relative pronoun
2. Change the verb to the present participle form
3. Place the present participle phrase after the modified noun

Examples:

- The man **who lives** near my home walks to work every day. -> Reduced: The man **living** near my home walks to work every day.
- The girl **who attends** my school lives at the end of the street. -> Reduced: The girl **attending** my school lives at the end of the street.

Comment: No, the verb doesn't correspond with the progressive aspect in the full relative clause. It should be "Situations which involve the purchase.."

Comment: @user178049 It's indeed so... the reduced relative clause changes the verb to a present participle.